# how to implement In-app purchase Android

Tags: java, android

I want to implement inapp purchase in my app which is a free app, It will ask to buy, after purchase the new apk replace the old apk. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to search in Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err, I think you'll need to take a different approach.

According to the Google Play Rules, "An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism." So you cannot change your apk.

But you have some options:

1. Create a 'pro' version on the Play Store
2. Have a app wide setting which changes the activity behaviour, or have 2 sets of activities, as you seem to already have made... This can be triggered by an in-app purchase. The docs for that are here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html